Collision with BoxColliders without Rigidbodies
So is it possible for 2 BoxCollider2D Objects to collide with each other provided both of them do not have Rigidbodies? I used Sebastian Lague's 2D tutorial where he doesn't use Rigidbodies.
I tried but didn't work, was expecting to find a method that would work.

When detecting a collision, it's important to ensure that:

Both GameObjects have a Behavior derived from Collider2D, regardless of it being Circle, Box, Capsule or custom.
The collision between 2 GameObjects, one with a 2D and another with a 3D Collider is not possible in any case
Either of 2 GameObjects or both have a Rigidbody2D
The Rigibody2D is simulated, regardless of its Body Type and both Collider2Ds having isTrigger enabled or not
The Rigidbody2D has to be either..., if Collider2D on the same GameObject has isTrigger

enabled

Dynamic
Kinematic


disabled

Dynamic
Kinematic, with Use full kinematic contacts enabled




A static Rigidbody2D does never detect collisions
If you have a Rigidbody2D on both GameObjects, the collision happens if either of them complies with the above mentioned rules
The method OnTriggerEnter2D is called when the Collider2D with the script that detects a collision is a trigger, otherwise OnCollisionEnter2D, regardless of the other Collider2D's type


Back to your question, it's impossible for 2 GameObjects with BoxCollider2Ds to collide with each other using methods like OnTriggerEnter2D or OnCollisionEnter2D without any of them having a Rigidbody2D.
If, for some reason, your still want them to collide with each other without having Rigidbody2Ds, you'll have to implement your custom collision-detection logic using e.g. Raycasts.
